# jquery - how to CUT LI elements from one UL to another UL

Tags: jquery

I would like to copy some LI's from one UL to another UL.

In my first UL I have 10 LI's and I would like to CUT 6,7,8,9,10 to another div.
How do I achieve it in jQuery ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do these easily with [`.slice`  *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`.appendTo`  *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$('#list1 > li').slice(5,10).appendTo('#list2');
// or to the end of list: 
// $('#list1 > li').slice(5).appendTo('#list2');
```

This will **move** the list elements to the other list. If you want to **copy** them, add [`.clone` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

If you want to move non-consecutive list elements, you have to select them differently.

Comment: what does $('#ul1 > li') means?

Comment: all `li` elements which are direct child of the `ul`

Comment: That was fast, didn't even had time to paste my solution into the form. ;)

Comment: I want to slice from the sixth element leaving only five elements in the original. does it mean I do slice(6, till the end)

Comment: @Alon: Fixed the code. According to [the documentation of `.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), you can omit the end argument. `start` should be `5` since `.slice` is `0`-based.

Comment: Is possible do even like that: ` $('#from li:nth-child(1n+6)').clone().appendTo('#target');` I suppose?

Comment: @FelixKling I can not test it now :-(

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Simply select the LIs you want to move and append them to the second UL.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the li elements with class `source`, slice and append into a new `ul` and finally append the `ul` to a container where ever you want.

```
$('<ul />').append($('ul#source li').slice(3,7)).appendTo(document.body);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JEj5A/3/)**